# How to make jQuery ajax call between sub-domains?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a domain like below.

I have two sub-domains within that as below.

http://foo.jayshit.info

http://bar.jayshit.info

I want to make a jQuery ajax call from foo.jayshit.info to bar.jayshit.info to get some html or to update some data back to server.

I know due to **same origin policy** its not that easy. and i do not want to use **JSONP** as well. because i want my ajax call to have **async: false** as below.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    url: tURL,
    data: tData,
    async: false
});
```

Please let me know if anyone came across some workaround for this.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are in control of the other sub-domain, you can send [this header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control) from bar.jayshit.info:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://foo.jayshit.info
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST
```

Modern browsers respect these headers and allow you to make the request. For IE8 you need to use [`XDomainRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc288060%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which is not supported by jQuery.

Comment: Thank you @Esailija 

Adding headers into Server does the trick except for IE as you have mentioned. 

still Finding solution for the same in IE :(

Comment: After adding headers in IIS server AJAX GET request did work on Chrome and Firefox only. AJAX GET request did not work on IE and Safari though.

But POST did not work across all browsers.

Comment: @JayshitLadani are you using `XDomainRequest` for IE? Remember it has to be done manually since jQuery is unaware of it.

Answer (score 0):

http://foo.jayshit.info and http://bar.jayshit.info is 2 different domains,so u need cross domain request, first link from google: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

use

```
dataType: "jsonp"
```

...

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    cache: false,
    url: tURL,
    data: tData,
    async: false
});
```

more info:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I know with **JSONP** as a dataType we can do but that is not a option for me.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you add the following to your code:

```
jQuery.support.cors = true;
```

See [this link](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8122) for further information

Answer (score 0):

The answer is both CORS and JSONP. IE does not support CORS yet, you will have to wait for IE10 to get that. JSONP only allows you to do cross domain GET not POST, PUT and DELETE. CORS does solve those problems and it is supported by all other browsers.

The other way you can solve this is to build a proxy in your website that will make the call from the server for you. This will get you around the cross domain issues in the browser. Those are in place as a security precaution in case you were wondering.